# Telegraf.js How to pass parameters to a function from inline keyboard

Tags: telegram-bot, telegraf, telegraf.js

I have an array of messages containing some text and an inline keyboard with "delete" button.

```
bot.command('items', ctx => {
    items.forEach(async data => {
        await ctx.reply(data.Title,
            Markup.inlineKeyboard([Markup.button.callback("delete item", "DeleteItem")]));
    })
})
```

And I have a function bot.action for the delete buttons on my inline keyboard. How do I pass a parameter to the bot.action so I can delete the item via the delete button.

```
bot.action("DeleteItem", async ctx => {
    ctx.reply("deleting item");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For delete message, you can use:

```js
bot.action('delete', ctx => ctx.deleteMessage())
```

As you can see from [examples/echo-bot-module.js](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/blob/v4/docs/examples/echo-bot-module.js).

If you need pass a parameter to the `bot.action`, you may try:

```js
bot.action(/^data-(\d+)$/, (ctx) => {
  return ctx.answerCbQuery(`Param: ${ctx.match[1]}! `)
})

// And send with callback data
Markup.button.callback('Button', `data-${Math.round(Math.random()*1000)}`)
```

Comment: There is no simple way to pass a parameter to a callback function!?